# Replace 0 for variable by special condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace all 0 in a column, but there are two constraints.

- Using .loc because there are 3 different values to be replace by the key
- Should replace all 0 without effect the other values

data

```
cw=

name         values
google        0
facebook      0
microsoft     0
google        2
facebook      55
microsoft     7
google        5
facebook      80
microsoft     66
```

My attempts

```
google =  99999
microsoft = 88888
facebook = 66666


# first attempt
cw.loc[cw['name'] == "Google"].replace(0, google) 
cw.loc[cw['name'] == "Bing"].replace(0, bing) 
cw.loc[cw['name'] == "Facebook"].replace(0, facebook) 



# second attempt
for x in cw.all():
    if cw.name== "Google":
        cw.loc[cw['values'] == 0, 'values'] = google
```

Neither works..

so the desired output is..

```
cw=

name         values
google        99999
facebook      66666
microsoft     88888
google        2
facebook      55
microsoft     7
google        5
facebook      80
microsoft     66
```

Comment: In your problem description, you've stated you want to replace if it's google, facebook, or microsoft. But in your "desired output" you only show google replaced. Which is the correct description?

Comment: @G.Anderson, question is updated now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want a map, and then it's matter of updating the correct location

```
maps = {'google':99999, 'microsoft': 88888, 'facebook': 66666}
to_replace = cw['name'].map(maps)

cw['values'] = np.where(cw['values'] == 0, to_replace, cw['values'])
```

Output:

```
        name  values
0     google   99999
1   facebook   66666
2  microsoft   88888
3     google       2
4   facebook      55
5  microsoft       7
6     google       5
7   facebook      80
8  microsoft      66
```

Answer (score 1):

Below solution is a modification of your first attempt

```
google =  99999
microsoft = 88888
facebook = 66666


cw.loc[cw['name'] == "google",'values'] = cw.loc[df['name'] == "google",'values'].replace(0, google) 

cw.loc[cw['name'] == "microsoft",'values'] = cw.loc[df['name'] == "microsoft",'values'].replace(0, microsoft) 

cw.loc[cw['name'] == "facebook",'values'] = cw.loc[df['name'] == "facebook",'values'].replace(0, facebook)
```

This works fine and meets the constraint(s).